# How to run Openboard after building it?

Tags: 20.04, compiling, directory, github, binary

I built Openboard with the help of **github**. I could find the binary of openboard but I couldn't run it! what I should do?

[github-openboard link](https://github.com/OpenBoard-org/OpenBoard/wiki/Build-from-source)

Comment: What do you mean _you couldn't run it_? Please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: Documentation (first Google hit): https://openboard.ch/support.en.html including PDF user's guide, YouTube videos

Comment: @HuHa Open-board doesn't support my version of Ubuntu(20.04) hence I built it using the help of GitHub, (I've given the link above). at then end after giving a successful make command, I was able to see a binary of Open-board in a folder. but it didn't open. I want to use open board but I'm stuck here! what should I do?